# Toggling auto-generated captions using YT.Player(); prohibiting mobile skip ahead

Tags: youtube-api

I need to disable a YouTube video's controls to finely control how users are allowed or not allowed to fast-forward, and then add most of them back as my own buttons using YT.Player(). Closed captioning is proving a challenge.

Setting playerVars{}'s cc_load_policy to 1 will work, but not with *self-generated* captions.

How can I offers users a button to toggle on/off self-generated captions?

Related: I understand video quality is *not* something I can control using YT.Player(). Is that true?

Finally, removing controls from the player *doesn't* seem to affect the mobile-only features where you can double-tap on the side of a video to skip 10 seconds ahead/behind; or the skip buttons and scrub bar that appear on the video when it's displayed full-screen on mobile devices.

Is there any way to controls those mobile-only features?